# Which way to use to replace a complete object with useState()?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-state

In my app I have an array of objects and a state which holds the current selected object. The object is not deep nested and contains only primitive types. The object comes from a click event. If I select a new object the state of the current selected object should be changed to the new object.
Data from the previous selected object is not needed. So what is the best way (performance wise, readable wise etc.) to change the state.

`const [currentSelectedObject, setCurrentSelectedObject] = useState();`

`setCurrentSelectedObject(newObject);`

or

`setCurrentSelectedObject({...currentSelectedObject, ...newObject});`

or

`setCurrentSelectedObject( currentSelectedObject => {...currentSelectedObject, ...newObject});`

Comment: `this.setState(object)`

Comment: @HoldOffHunger I don't think, that this is possible in a React function component.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to set `currentSelectedObject` to a completely new object:

```
setCurrentSelectedObject(newObject);
```

If you want to **add `newObject`'s properties into the existing, previously set `currentSelectedObject`** you would use either of the other two methods.

Answer (score 0):

The `setCurrentSelectedObject(newObject)` is the best in this case.

Construction `setCurrentSelectedObject({...currentSelectedObject, ...newObject})`
looks dangerous, because this way `currentSelectedObject` is **stale** from the last render time, and states between last render time and current will be lost.